# Appropriate Join query

Tags: sql, firebird

[image]

I have a table as shown above.I am trying to select rows as shown below but not being able to do so.

```
LP_DATE     LP_VCHNO       LP_LEDGID    LP_DRAMT        LP_CRAMT
-----------------------------------------------------------------
01.04.2016  Ctra#001       1             400.00000      0.00000
                           3               0.00000      2000.00000
                           7               0.00000      2000.00000
01.04.2016  Pymnt#000001   5             300.00000         0.00000
                           1               0.00000       300.00000
```

I guess a Self Join query has to be used but i am not able to figure it out.Please advise how the desired result could be achieved.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt if you can achieve this in a single query. This is because you want to show the first record of each group for the first two columns and put remaining as null. This seems to be a formatting problem. You can use a cursor and achieve this programmatically

Comment: If you are using Firebird 3.0 you could achieve something like that using window functions

Answer (score 0):

Your result table is strange because it has blank values in the first two columns.  Other than that issue, it seems to simply be an `order by` and `select`:

```
select LP_DATE, LP_VCHNO, LP_LEDGID, LP_DRAMT, LP_CRAMT
from t
order by LP_DATE, LP_VCHNO, LP_ID;
```

Comment: @Zack and Gordon thanks for your reply.At the present i am using query similar to as mentioned by Gordon.As per Zack's suggestion i would  try to use a cursor my desired result and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN I_MIN.LP_DATE IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE I.LP_DATE END AS LP_DATE
    , CASE WHEN I_MIN.LP_DATE IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE I.LP_VCHNO END AS LP_VCHNO
    , I.LP_LEDGID
    , I.LP_DRAMT
    , I.LP_CRAMT
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE I
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        I.LP_DATE
        , MIN(I.LP_LEDGID) AS MIN_LP_LEDGID
    FROM
        YOUR_TABLE I
    GROUP BY
        I.LP_DATE) AS I_MIN ON I.LP_DATE = I_MIN.LP_DATE AND I.LP_LEDGID = I_MIN.MIN_LP_LEDGID
ORDER BY
    I.LP_DATE
    , I.LP_LEDGID
```